# rxjs: how can I get informed of an unsubscription of an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, switchmap

I have an Angular project where HTTP-searches are started by typing in an input field. This is done like the examples on the web with following code (simplified):

```js
this.form.valueChanges.pipe (
  debounceTime (this.dueTime),
  distinctUntilChanged (compare),
  switchMap (() => async$()
);

function async$ {
    count++;
    return load$ ().pipe (tap ((response: T) => {
        count--;
        ...
      },error => {
        count--;
        ...
      }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but everytime `async$` is started, a counter will be increased and when it is finished, the counter will be decreased again.
So when the subscription is unsubscribed by `switchMap`, the count is increased but not decreased again, because the success or error method are never called.

So my question is: is there a possibility to get noticed of the cancellation of the subscription so that I can decrease the counter?

It is not an option to put the count logic out of `async$` because the function is used elsewhere.

Comment: use the `finalize()` operator

Comment: why do you need to know when the unscubscription on async$() happens?

Comment: Because when the observable is cancelled between count++ and count--, the counter is wrong.